# Подгрузка в ListView данных из Firebase БД

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Реализую проект  под Android  с использованием Firebase Real Time базы данных. Нужно реализовать список товаров визуально как в Авито.То есть, сначала 5 товаров, когда скроллишь вниз, то появляется `ProgressBar` и подгружается еще 5. По умолчанию Firebase Reference вытягивает все товары. Как грамотнее сделать?

1. Вытащить все, но засунуть в `ListView` только 5 товаров, а потом на слушатель `ListView.ScrollListener` цеплять `ProgressBar` и в `ArrayList` в адаптере эддить по 5 товаров?
2. Сделать Query Firebase Reference с отсейкой по 5 товаров и при скролле делать новые запросы к базе Firebase.

Никак не могу найти компромисс!

1. Долго грузиться в начале, но потом подгрузка быстрая и нет нагрузки на бд
2. Первый раз грузиться быстро, но подгрузка медленнее и больше обращений к базе.

Comment: 2. Только с чего решили, что подгрузка медленная?

Comment: не медленная, а медленнее чем в 1 варианте.неправильно выразился

Answer (score 0):

Так как вы хотите уменьшить нагрузку на базу, то реализуйте второй подход. Через query делайте запросы и стройте пейджинг. Тогда вам другой вопрос - а как вы будете отслеживать изменение данных на первой странице?

С другой стороны, придумали ValueEventListener() и ChildEventListener() совсем для других целей. И посмотрите в сторону Firestore, это более гибкое решение, чем RealTime Database